# what is minimum flash player revision working with FLEX 3

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flex3

My page has currently this set up - what is minimum REVISION I can configure here:

```
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 124;
```

For example my MacOSX ibook machine does not start this page at all, it just says "you are trying to install flash palyer on unsupported OS"

So I really like to keep version requirement as minimum as possible.

Comment: mac seem to have 9,0,47,  should it work OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/systemreqs/). It looks like its best to have 9.0.124.0. Which means you will need to upgrade your Macbook flash player.

Comment: well, my Mac book cannot be upgraded,  its no more supported by Adobe.  I am going to set it to 9,0,47 just in case.

Comment: In that cases, I'd say keep your fingers crossed and keep hoping things will work out just fine. Let us know if you face more issues.